# How to make AspectJ and Lombok co-work with maven?

Tags: java, maven, aspectj, lombok

I've tried the way in this link: https://palesz.wordpress.com/2011/12/03/howto-maven-lombok-and-aspectj-together/

But the error shows:

```
[ERROR] no sources specified
    <unknown source file>:<no line information>

[ERROR] AspectJ Compiler 1.8.9

    Usage: <options> <source file | @argfile>..
```

I used the plugin like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.10</version>
    <configuration>
        <verbose>true</verbose>
        <showWeaveInfo />
        <forceAjcCompile>true</forceAjcCompile>
        <sources />
        <complianceLevel>1.8</complianceLevel>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>process-classes</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
                <goal>test-compile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

And the relevant dependencies are:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.10</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.10</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score -1):

I followed the same post to make it work, but you forgot one thing (I forgot as well).

You'll need to add the weaveDirectories to the configuration:

```
<weaveDirectories>
  <weaveDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</weaveDirectory>
</weaveDirectories>
```

This reason why is quite obvious as the sources tag is empty, the aspectj-maven-plugin needs something to work with.

Hope this helps.